# Nextjs Vercel Cloudinary ERROR 405 only in PRODUCTION

Tags: next.js, cors, vercel, cloudinary, uploading

Please help, 2 weeks stuck. So far no answers works, no AI, nobody, no workaround, I have no idea where to look anymore.

Uploading images on development works perfect, on production 405. Add headers, take headers, change CORS, use Axios, change to fetch, clear cache, downgrade Nextjs, try different npm's etc... No idea on what to do next.

ON FRONT

```
const createImagesSrc = async (

    imageFileToAdd: File[]

  ): Promise<AxiosResponse | null> => {

    try {

      const formData = new FormData();

      imageFileToAdd.forEach((image) => {

        formData.append("images", image);

      });

      const uploadResponse = await axios.post("/api/upload", formData, {

      })

      if (uploadResponse.status === 200) {

        uploadResponse.data.uploadResponses.forEach(

          (response: any, index: number) => {

            imageSrc.push(response.secure_url);

          }

        );

        return uploadResponse;

      } else {

        console.error("Failed to upload images");

        return null;

      }

    } catch (error) {

      console.error(error);

      return null;

    }

  };
```

ON BACK

```
cloudinary.config({

  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,

  api_key: process.env.API_KEY,

  api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET,

});



export async function POST(request: Request) {

  const data = await request.formData();

  const files = data.getAll("images");



  if (files.length === 0) {

    return NextResponse.json({

      success: false,

      message: "No images to upload.",

    });

  }



  const uploadPreset = "yfhyp9my";

  const uploadResponses: any[] = [];



  for (const file of files) {

    // @ts-ignore

    const bytes = await file.arrayBuffer();

    const buffer = Buffer.from(bytes);



    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      cloudinary.uploader

        .upload_stream({ upload_preset: uploadPreset }, (error, result) => {

          if (error) {

            reject(error);

          }

          resolve(result);

        })

        .end(buffer);

    });

    uploadResponses.push(response);

  }

  return NextResponse.json({ success: true, uploadResponses });

}
```

NEXT.CONFIG.JS

```
const nextConfig = {

  async headers() {

    return [

      {

        // matching all API routes

        source: "/api/:path*",

        headers: [

          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },

          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "coolbananas.org, localhost:3000" },

          {

            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",

            value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT",

          },

          {

            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",

            value:

              "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version",

          },

        ],

      },

    ];

  },

  images: {

    remotePatterns: [

      {

        protocol: "https",

        hostname: "res.cloudinary.com",

        port: "",

        pathname: "/jpsm83/image/upload/**",

      },

      {

        protocol: "https",

        hostname: "lh3.googleusercontent.com",

      },

      {

        protocol: "https",

        hostname: "restcountries.com",

      },

    ],

  },

};
```

ERROR

POST https://www.coolbananas.org/api/upload 405 (Method Not Allowed)

AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 405', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

code

:

"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"

config

:

{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}

message

:

"Request failed with status code 405"

name

:

"AxiosError"

request

:

XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}

response

:

config

:

adapter

:

(2) ['xhr', 'http']

data

:

FormData {}

env

:

{FormData: ƒ, Blob: ƒ}

headers

:

AxiosHeaders {Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*', Content-Type: false}

maxBodyLength

:

-1

maxContentLength

:

-1

method

:

"post"

timeout

:

0

transformRequest

:

[ƒ]

transformResponse

:

[ƒ]

transitional

:

{silentJSONParsing: true, forcedJSONParsing: true, clarifyTimeoutError: false}

url

:

"/api/upload"

validateStatus

:

ƒ (e)

xsrfCookieName

:

"XSRF-TOKEN"

xsrfHeaderName

:

"X-XSRF-TOKEN"

[[Prototype]]

:

Object

data

:

""

headers

:

AxiosHeaders {access-control-allow-credentials: 'true', access-control-allow-headers: 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Ver…h, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version', access-control-allow-methods: 'GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT', access-control-allow-origin: 'coolbananas.org, localhost:3000', cache-control: 'public, max-age=0, must-revalidate', …}

request

:

XMLHttpRequest

onabort

:

ƒ ()

onerror

:

ƒ ()

onload

:

null

onloadend

:

ƒ onloadend()

onloadstart

:

null

onprogress

:

null

onreadystatechange

:

null

ontimeout

:

ƒ ()

readyState

:

4

response

:

""

responseText

:

""

responseType

:

""

responseURL

:

"https://www.coolbananas.org/api/upload"

responseXML

:

null

status

:

405

statusText

:

""

timeout

:

0

upload

:

XMLHttpRequestUpload

onabort

:

null

onerror

:

null

onload

:

null

onloadend

:

null

onloadstart

:

null

onprogress

:

null

ontimeout

:

null

[[Prototype]]

:

XMLHttpRequestUpload

withCredentials

:

false

[[Prototype]]

:

XMLHttpRequest

status

:

405

statusText

:

""

[[Prototype]]

:

Object

stack

:

"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 405\n    at settle (https://www.coolbananas.org/_next/static/chunks/118-3737272d4a0dcc07.js:37:18624)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (https://www.coolbananas.org/_next/static/chunks/118-3737272d4a0dcc07.js:37:21902)"

[[Prototype]]

:

Error

This is an issue only in PRODUCTION mode, development is fine. All "keys" been add to Vercel and Vercel is working properly once I can save all data to MongoDB but the images doesnt get create at Cloudinary. I tryed to update CORS at Cloudinary but seen to have no such option on their website. Very frustate, I got pretty bad stuck ;(

- Try to downgrade Nextjs
- Try to add differents npm to handle CORS
- Try to change Axios for Fetch
- Try to add headers manualy 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' on front
- Try to config CORS at next.config.js
- Try every single blog about similar issue
- Try every single answers fron AI
- Try all cloudinary management console docs
- Try to cry for about 10 min
- Nothing works

Comment: Neither `coolbananas.org` nor `localhost:3000` are valid [Web-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) values. Instead, try `https://coolbananas.org` and `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: Still same error, i believe the issue is on cloudinary. Some how i suppose to be able to enable cors on production (https://coolbananas.org) on cloudinary website but there was no such options there. I also open a case on cloudinary but no response yet. I found out more people are having same issue on production

Comment: Hey there, if you try this solution does it work? 

https://community.cloudinary.com/discussion/439/405-cloudinary-only-on-production-using-vercel-nextjs

Comment: no it doesnt work but i found a solution. the problem is on the .upload_stream, i got a way around with some help from cloudinary developers.

Comment: https://community.cloudinary.com/discussion/439/405-cloudinary-only-on-production-using-vercel-nextjs#latest